# Microsoft Edge broswer not working with web listener ASP.NET 5.0 DNX

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am sure many of you tried DNX to open the web listener and test your web command
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"

Once you run the "web" command, if you try to access this link http://localhost:5000 on Micrsoft Edge / Windows 10, it says, Can't reach this page. It works on Google Chrome though.

Remind you neither Windows 10 nor Microsoft Edge or DNX have been released yet.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Edge runs in network isolation and does not currently support localhost testing. Run this in an elevated command prompt to enable loopback support:

`CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

In a future update, you’ll be able to enable localhost loopback support using `about:flags`.

More info: http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/how-can-i-debug-localhost/